# Directories and Dynamic Paging PHP

Tags: php, javascript, css, directory

Im working on a dynamic paging website (Essentially clicking a link and it loads the content without a page-refresh (ajax).

My problem is when I got `example.com/first/second` it messes up the javascript and css directories (as the browser can't find those since it's doing `/first/example.css` and not `/example.css`). I tried doing:

```
    $Dots = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

And adding that before the link to my css/javascript. This didn't work, so what can I do?

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` gives you the path up-to the document root, where your website begins. So you actually want everything past document root, not including document root as far as a browser is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the absolute path to the css file

/path/to/css_file.css (note the slash beore path)

you should do the same thing for the javascript files